# How to upload python modules on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, module

I have Django app, which I deployed on Heroku. 
All the modules were deployed whith requirements.txt and everything is ok

But I also have several classes which are made as modules in separate .py files. On local machine these modules are in `...\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\modules\` folder

Now I need to upload these modules to Heroku. But I don't know how to do it. Is there any file manager program for windows, which allows to connect to heroku server and upload these /modules/ folder to the site-packages directory?

I've tried to find such a program, but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Deploy the app**
In this step you will deploy the app to Heroku.

Create an app on Heroku, which prepares Heroku to receive your source code:
`$ heroku create`

When you create an app, a git remote (called heroku) is also created and associated with your local git repository.

Heroku generates a random name (in this case serene-caverns-82714) for your app, or you can pass a parameter to specify your own app name.

Now deploy your code:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

The application is now deployed. Ensure that at least one instance of the app is running:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Now visit the app at the URL generated by its app name. As a handy shortcut, you can open the website as follows:

```
$ heroku open
```

Comment: I've already done all these steps. My app is already deployed

Comment: But I need to upload my modules there. Which are in ...\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\modules\ folder at the moment